# Waterlogged Acer

Tags: repotting, maple

I have a large Shirasawanum Aureum Acer potted in large glazed pot.  Unfortunately the large roots have grown through the drainage hole and into the ground blocking drainage so it is now very waterlogged.if I cut off the thick roots coming out of drainage hole will it kill the tree? It is so pot bound that I think I will have to break the pot to free the plant, unless you have any suggestions on how to get it out of the pot without destroying the rather expensive pot.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is lay it on its side and drill one or more drain hole with masonry bits in the bottom. I have drilled many unglazed and a few glazed pots. You may get some small chipping of glaze at the edge of the hole. It sounds like you are likely to lose the plant or pot so it seems worth the chance ( depending on experience there is a chance of cracking ceramics). A relatively easy choice for me as I have several drills and many bits. If you need to buy equipment it could be more costly than the pot. Pottery drilling is easier if one starts with a small bit, like 1/8 " , then drill larger holes; keeping the bit wet.